# Change PowerShell display settings when running an .exe program

Tags: windows, terminal

I have a simple .exe program that prints messages to the Windows terminal (console). This program is operated by someone who needs the font size to be as big as possible.

Is it possible to change the display properties of the terminal window (e.g., font size) that would apply just to that .exe file? I know how to change the display properties manually, but I'm looking for an automatic solution that would apply only to one particular .exe file.

I can change the (conhost) terminal window size by

```
mode WIDTH, HEIGHT
```

but it seems there is no way to change the font size from within the program.

I do not need to be able to change the font size from within the program since the wanted font-size value is known before the .exe program starts. **I just need something automatic.**

---

To give more context, the .exe program in question is an application for my kid to practice simple addition and subtraction:

[image]

Comment: The font size is set by the terminal handler (command prompt, PowerShell, Windows Terminal)

Comment: Is there a way to change the font size with a script or a configuration file? Having to do this manually is tedious... I find it unbelievable that there is no way to "pipe" the commands to the terminal handler, but to "click" everything you want to change.

Comment: Windows Terminal supports profiled which allows you to preconfigure what font size you want.

Comment: Your can find the console cmdlet `Set-ConsoleFont` described in the article [Change PowerShell console font size with a cmdlet](https://4sysops.com/archives/change-powershell-console-font-size-with-cmdlet/). The script link in the article is invalid now, but can still be found in [Github](https://github.com/MikeFal/PowerShell/blob/master/SetConsoleFont/SetConsoleFont.psm1). Is this what you're looking for?